# how to create circular import from view to model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I know how to avoid this pitfall, what does a circular import look like from a model to a view and view to model?

Also what would be a solution to the example given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the module, not the name. Don't attempt to use the name until it has been defined.

```
import foo
```

...

```
import bar

def baz():
  bar.quux
```

Comment: is the "import foo" the model? How are you referencing foo in the view without importing it?

Comment: which code snippet goes to view and model?  Is this what not to do or what to do?

Comment: One is the view, the other is the model. The text describes what to do.